# cyrillic NSString in objective-c MySQL

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I'm using mySql objective-c library: http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/
and trying to use cyrillic symbols in LIKE statement:

```
NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select id,qrId,name,surname from users where name like '%%%@%%'",_nameField.text];
    userFetch = [MysqlFetch fetchWithCommand:cmd onConnection:myConnection];
```

it works with english characters, but with cyrillic symbols in _nameField.text I receive this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'MysqlException', reason: 'Could not perform mysql_stmt_bind_result() Error #1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%–∞%' at line 1'

in MysqlFetch.m my command (s) is converted to UT8String and this cause an exception in mysql_stmt_prepare:

```
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(myStatement, [s UTF8String],[s length])) {
  [MysqlException raiseConnection:connection
                       withFormat:@"Could not perform mysql_stmt_bind_result() Error #%d:%s"
   ,mysql_errno(connection.connection),
   mysql_error(connection.connection)];
}
```

I can do Insert with cyrylic NSStrings using MysqlInsert. It doesn't cause an exception because there no field values (which may contain cyrillic symbols), only field names:

```
NSArray *keys = [rowData allKeys];

NSMutableString *cmd = [NSMutableString string];
[cmd appendFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ ( ",table];
BOOL firstAdd=YES;
for (NSString *columnName in keys) {
  if (firstAdd) {
    [cmd appendFormat:@" %@ ",[columnName mysqlEscapeInConnection:connection]];
    firstAdd=NO;
  } else {
    [cmd appendFormat:@", %@ ",[columnName mysqlEscapeInConnection:connection]];
  }
}

[cmd appendFormat:@" ) values ( ",table];

firstAdd=YES;
for (NSString *columnName in keys) {
  if (firstAdd) {
    [cmd appendString:@" ? "];
    firstAdd=NO;
  } else {
    [cmd appendString:@", ? "];
  }
}
[cmd appendFormat:@" ) "];

MYSQL_STMT *myStatement = mysql_stmt_init(connection.connection);

if (mysql_stmt_prepare(myStatement, [cmd UTF8String],[cmd length])) {
  [MysqlException raiseConnection:connection withFormat: @"mysql_stmt_prepare failed %@ %s",cmd, mysql_stmt_error(myStatement)];
}
```

and values are added later:

```
NSObject *object = [rowData objectForKey:key];
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *s = (NSString *)object;
    const char *ch = [s UTF8String];
    binding[x].is_null= 0;
    binding[x].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING; 
    binding[x].buffer = (void *)ch;
    binding[x].buffer_length= strlen(ch);        
  }
```

May be too many text and simple question:
how can I convert cyrillic NSString to use with MysqlUpdate?